# Tv Frame for Video Positioning

Tags: html, css

Im wondering if someone could assist with a possible solution for a strange positioning thing I have to do

I have a Video that needs to be on the home page then have a Tv like Image "Frame" Around it  And then have them scale together

[image]

SO what ive tried is to take the middle border out keep the tv outline, Then create. a container then stretch the image the full container and then Im finding it difficult to get the video on the center even when I Margin:Auto because the container is smaller then the Image

html

```
<?php
get_header();
?>
<section class="Home-main">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="sidebar-space col-xs-0 col-sm-3 col-lg-2">

        </div>
        <div class="content col-xs-12 col-sm-9 col-lg-10">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="home-video">
                       <img class="h-video" src="<?php echo home_url();?>/wp-content/uploads/2020/06/Tv-Frame.png">
                    <iframe src="https://player.vimeo.com/video/427699658" width="640" height="480" frameborder="0" allow="autoplay; fullscreen" allowfullscreen></iframe>

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>  
    </div>
</section>

<?php
get_footer();
?>
```

Css

```
.Home-main{
    background-image: url("http://localhost/Gummy-Vital/wp-content/uploads/2020/06/Home-back.png");
    height:4500px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

.home-video{
    position:relative;
    margin-top:40px;
}

.h-video{
    width:100%;
    height:auto;
        position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
}
```

PS: ignore the Height for the page its just so that I can make sure the background meets up correctly.

I plan on adding a Border around the Video to create the inner border 
What I end up with:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You could achieve this in different ways:

With absolute positioning like you started to :

```
.home-video{
  position:relative;
}

.h-video{
  position: absolute;
  width:100%;
  height:auto;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

Or using flexbox :

```
.home-video {
  display flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.h-video {
  width:100%;
  height:auto;
}
```